# image slide conflicting with another div

Tags: jquery, html, slider

Well my codes working ok but just that if i add multiple div e.g.
the moment i load the page the first div album plays images and the second one disappears but when the first div album  image reaches last image then the slider starts playing in the second div album. Hope i m not confusing?

please take a look at the fiddle what exactly is happening

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x217hseb/15/)

```
<div class="imgslide">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/room1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/room2.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/room3.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/room4.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/room5.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/room6.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @divy3993 now how to fix the conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each album and attach the functionality to them like

```js
$(function() {
  $('.albums').each(function() {

    var currentIndex = 0,
      $album = $(this),
      items = $('.imgslide div', this),
      itemAmt = items.length;

    function cycleItems() {
      var item = $('.imgslide div', $album).eq(currentIndex);
      items.hide();
      item.css('display', 'inline-block');
    }

    var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
      currentIndex += 1;
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      cycleItems();
    }, 2000);

    $('.next', this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      clearInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex += 1;
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      cycleItems();
    });

    $('.prev', this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      clearInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
      }
      cycleItems();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.albums {
  position: relative;
}
.imgslide {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.imgslide div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.imgslide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.next {
  right: 1px;
  border-right: 3px solid #DC6242;
}
.prev {
  left: 1px;
  border-left: 3px solid #DC6242;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The albums are dynamically generated and im just trying to slide the thumb images but something is just not ok -->

<div class="albums">
  <h2>Album Name: <?php echo $albumname; ?> </h2>
  <div class="imgslide">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="http://pawmax.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/2dogs1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.eastcountymagazine.org/sites/eastcountymagazine.org/files/dog%20show2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://wpelegacy.redfm.ie/2013/07/dogs2-e1373638129723-200x100.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/hipster-dogs-ft-200x100.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="next">&raquo;</a>
  <a href="#" class="prev">&laquo;</a>
</div>

<!-- Second Albim in same page -->

<div class="albums">
  <h2>Album Name: <?php echo $albumname; ?> </h2>
  <div class="imgslide">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="http://pawmax.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/2dogs1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.eastcountymagazine.org/sites/eastcountymagazine.org/files/dog%20show2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://wpelegacy.redfm.ie/2013/07/dogs2-e1373638129723-200x100.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/hipster-dogs-ft-200x100.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="next">&raquo;</a>
  <a href="#" class="prev">&laquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: almost doing like i wanted it to but the next and previous buttons are not showing individually any idea bro?

Comment: thanks so much bro really appreciate your time and kindness. also how to remove the auto slides from it?